# Javascript - How to add 'br' into paragraph

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm using backbone.js for my mobile app project. My question is how to add 'br' into paragraph? This is my code.

```
<p><%= product.get('description') %></p>
```

Data in database

```
The COOLPIX S620 combines beauty and brains. 
It features the worlds fastest start up in just 0.7 seconds.
```

What I want is be like this

```
The COOLPIX S620 combines beauty and brains. 

It features the worlds fastest start up in just 0.7 seconds.
```

Not this

```
The COOLPIX S620 combines beauty and brains. It features the worlds fastest start up in just 0.7 seconds.
```

Comment: Split by `. ` join with `<br/>`

Comment: @elclanrs - That would be a little risky as he might end up having `<br>`s where they shouldn't be. For ex: `0.7` would become `0<br>7`

Comment: Yeah, just giving a tip there, in the hopes OP will try something and post code

Comment: What delimits your paragraphs? New lines?

Comment: if he splitted by `.` then what about `just 0.7` used in paragraph?

Comment: he can do split by combination of dot and space `.` or ` `.

Comment: Off topic, but it should be `world's fastest`

Comment: Presumably the db uses \n or \r\n to represent paragraph breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex in javascript to add a line break after every sentence.

The search parameter for the period followed by a capital letter is `/\.(?=[A-Z])/g`

```
description.replace(/\.(?=[A-Z])/g, '<br />');
```